# How can i make my app to draw over others and be shown in a small window?

Tags: java, android, xml

As the title says I want to make my app to be shown in a small window(smaller version of it) and to be able to draw over other apps. I have no idea how and where to search about it.
I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me on where to search about it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Picture-in-picture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture)

Comment: I suggest you to simply google for something like "android draw over other apps tutorial". There's dozens of websites that could help you out.

Comment: I tried it but i dont think this is what i want.I want the user to be able to press buttons from my app(interact with the app) this got me thinking if its even possible.I basically want the user to be able to multitask something like having it on one half of the screen.